# How to edit controls in a system::thread.

Tags: c++-cli

I need to be able to add items to a listbox inside of a thread. Code is below:

```
1. ref class Work
2. {
3. public:
4.  static void RecieveThread()
5.      {
6.      while (true)
7.      {
8.          ZeroMemory(cID, 64);
9.          ZeroMemory(message, 256);
10.         if(recv(sConnect, message, 256, NULL) != SOCKET_ERROR && recv(sConnect, cID, 64, NULL) != SOCKET_ERROR)
11.         {
12.             ID = atoi(cID);
13.             String^ meep = gcnew String(message);
14.             lbxMessages->Items->Add(meep);
15.             check = 1;
16.         }
17.     }
18. }
19. };
```

I get the error 
 `Error: a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object` on line `14.` 
Is there any way to get it to let me do that? Because if I try to use `String^ meep;`  outside of that Thread it doesn't contain anything. It works PERFECT when I use it within the thread but not outside of it. I need to be able to add that message to the list-box. If anyone can help I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show how lbxMessages is defined, but I'm going to assume that it's a non-static data member in the same class. If that's the case, then you need to specify which object you want to access `lbxMessages` on. The simplest way would be to switch the RecieveThread method to be non-static, then you can access `this->lbxMessages`.

You didn't say which windowing toolkit you're using, but you probably will need to Invoke back onto the UI thread in order to edit the control.

Answer (score 0):

One way is using System::Thread with a ParameterizedThreadStart delegate, which let you pass objects, in this case lbxMessages.

```
ParameterizedThreadStart^ threadCallback;
threadCallback = gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart(&Work::ReceiveThread);
Thread^ recvThread = gcnew Thread( threadCallback );
recvThread->Start( lbxMessages );
```

Your static method for running the thread:

```
static void RecieveThread(Object^ state)
{
    ListBox^ lbxMessages = (ListBox^)state;
    //...code
}
```

But.. . there is another problem. Assuming ListBox is a Win32 control, you can make changes in control only from the thread which it was created. So every time you insert a ListBox item, it must be done from the UI's thread. One way is using a [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) object.

```
 // Start the thread
 array<Object^>^ args = gcnew array<Object^>(2){
    lbxMessages,
    SynchronizationContext::Current
 }
 recvThread->Start( args);
```

Thread method should be something like this:

```
static void RecieveThread(Object^ state)
{
  array<Object^>^ args = (array<Object^>^)state;
  ListBox^ lbxMessages = (ListBox^)args[0];
  SynchronizationContext^ ctx = (SynchronizationContext^)args[1];
  //...code
     String^ meep = gcnew String(message);
     ctx->Send(gcnew SendOrPostCallback(&Work::SafeListBoxInsert),
               gcnew array<Object^>(2){lbxMessages, meep}
     );
}
```

You will need another method to be called from UI's thread and make the changes.

```
ref class Work{
  //...other methods
  static void SafeListBoxInsert(Object^ state)
  {
    array<Object^>^ args = (array<Object^>^)state;
    ListBox^ lst = (ListBox^) args[0];
    String^ item = (String^) args[1];
    lst->Items->Add(item);
  }
}
```